# Tab bar disappearing when switching controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, object, tabbar

This code works perfectly to switch view controllers,except the tab bar controller disappears.
Now I try many different variations of this code

> [self presentViewController:homeNavigationController animated:NO completion:nil];

But none of them seems to work properly. The push controller just freezes the view in place. Any tips on what to do?

```
 - (void)_tabBarItemClicked:(id)item {   
assert([item isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]);



NSInteger selectedIndex = ((UIButton *)item).tag;

[self setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex];

[self _setSelectedItemAtIndex:selectedIndex];



NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"index": [NSNumber numberWithInt:selectedIndex]};

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"tabBarDidSelectItem" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
if (selectedIndex ==2) {

    HomeViewController *homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *homeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];

    [self presentViewController:homeNavigationController animated:NO completion:nil];

}}
```

Comment: You've asked various questions relating to Tab Bars, all of which seem to indicate a lack of understanding of UITabBarController.  Perhaps you'd be well-served reading the documentation on it:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html  Also, Apple even provides an "application designed to show how to build a tab-bar based iOS application", Tabster:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tabster/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

You're presenting homeNavigationController modally -- what you're seeing is the normal behavior of a modal view controller, that is, they take over the whole screen including the tab bar. If you want to see the tab bar, then don't use a modal presentation.

Comment: Ok, what will be the best way to present a view controller. Push? Because I tried that but causes problems.

Comment: @FelixJones, it all depends what you're trying to do. I can't really advise you without knowing more about the structure of your app, and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeNavigationController animated:NO]; I tried this method but nothing happened.

Comment: @FelixJones, that means nothing to me without knowing your app structure. What controller is that code in? You need to edit your question to show what controllers you have where, and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by:

1) Define YourTabBarController object in AppDelegate

2) And presentViewController from YourTabBarController's object instead of 'self' like

```
[appDelegateObj.yourTabBarObj presentViewController:homeNavigationController animated:NO completion:nil];];
```

Make sure your Appdelegate object is initialized.

Comment: Hope you understand if not let me know i will post detailed code.